# Any way of using java.nio.* to interrupt a InputStream#read() without closing socket?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Do you know of a way to interrupt a read from a Java `InputStream` without closing the associated socket?

Here is the current construction strategy for grabbing a socket input stream and converting to an interruptible DataInputStream:

```
InputStream interruptibleInputStream = Channels.newInputStream(Channels.newChannel(m_ConnectionData.getSocket().getInputStream()));
DataInputStream myInterruptibleDIS = new DataInputStream(interruptibleInputStream);
```

This makes use of a `ReadableByteChannel` which offers a `read(ByteBuffer)` method with support for a `ClosedByInterruptException` throwable.

The problem is that calling an interrupt on the thread making `read()` calls on the `DataInputStream` causes the underlying socket to be closed.

For my context I need the socket to remain open; the `read` call is awaiting user input which isn't coming, so I'm using the interrupt to pass control back to a higher component and then ultimately returning to `read` again.

I'd be very grateful if someone could suggest a way to achieve this using JDK inbuilt classes, or perhaps pointing out that it's not possible with some information.

I understand there are other ways to achieve the same effect, but nevertheless am curious to know whether this approach is feasible.

Comment: You can use a `Selector` and `.select(int)` on the socket.

Comment: set a read timeout on the socket.

Comment: @fge - Thank you. I've investigated what you suggested and it looks plausible. So if I run mySelector.select() in my thread instead of read() directly, then interrupt the thread, the socket will remain open?

Comment: No. If you interrupt an `InterruptibleChannel` during a read it will be closed and throw a `ClosedByInterruptException`. If you just want a read timeout, don't use a channel at all, just a regular Socket; call `Socket.setSoTimeout()` with a shortish timeout, and check the `isInterrupted()` status of the thread every time the timeout triggers. Better still, review your requirement to interrupt the thread. What's that for?

Comment: @EJP - I did exactly as you suggested, putting the read() in a WHILE that only ends if a successful read has accomplished and continues while a SocketTimeoutException has been received. I exit if Thread.interrupted() is true. It works perfectly as you'd expect. Many thanks indeed for the advice, much appreciated :-) Feel free to paste your response into an answer, I'll mark it as the chosen one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you interrupt an InterruptibleChannel during a read, it will be closed and throw a ClosedByInterruptException. If you just want a read timeout, don't use a channel at all, just a regular Socket; call Socket.setSoTimeout() with a shortish timeout, and check the isInterrupted() status of the thread every time the timeout triggers. Better still, review your requirement to interrupt the thread. What's that for?