# stream readLine to close with interruption

Tags: java

I have a thread, which reads input from `getInputStream` of a `Process`. It waits for readLine.

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream));
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
String s = read.readLine();
process(s);
}
```

But it turns out that `readLine` doesn't respond to interrupt status. So during shutdown, it doesn't let the JVM to shutdown. On browsing the source code, it looks that they just poll till the have a `\n` line terminating character.

Any alternatives or hacks?

PS: It is a duplicate of [How to interrupt BufferedReader's readLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595926/how-to-interrupt-bufferedreaders-readline?rq=1). Hence I am closing it

Comment: Are the missing `()` in `process.getInputStream` a typo?

Comment: How do you interrupt `readLine()`?

Comment: I interrupt the thread which is executing it

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be :

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
```

Comment: @Jatin Glad it helped, don't forget to validate the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

A reliable way to stop a process is Process.destroy. Save a reference to the process in a field and call Process.destroy instead of interrupting the thread.

Answer (score 0):

From [`Thread.interrupt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.

But [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) does not implement [`InterruptibleChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html). So, this is the reason why your thread is stuck in the call to `readLine()`.