# Java listening to socket while checking time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an issue,

My client needs to listen from a server for a particular amount of time, and if it does not receive a reply from server in that time it has to close the connection.

I had two threads in client, one updates the boolean variable to false after the time expired, and other thread checks for msg from server as well as timer.

My code is something like this:

```
while(true){
    if(l=is.readLine().equals(msg))
    {
        // do processing
        break;
    }
    if(timer)
        break;
}
```

so my while loop continuously checks for msg and timer.
The problem is is.readline() is blocking the call, and is indefinetely waiting for msg from server.

How do I go about it?

I tried

```
if(l=is.readLine()!=null and l.equals(msg))
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone guys...

I found a simple solution to this problem...

Im checking if there is data in the buffer before calling the readline

```
if(ir.ready())
    ir.readLine()
```

The abouve will call readLine only if its non blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can check both conditions but this is far more complicate IMHO than having a thread which polls your connections and closes the ones which have timed out.

i.e. have a thread which wakes every second or so and calls a checkTimeout() method of every connection in a list of connections.  If the checkTimeout detects the timeout has been reached it sets a `closed = true;` volatile flag and close()s the connection.  If an exception is thrown, I ignore it if if occurred after the connection was closed.

You can use a SocketTimeout, but this doesn't always appear to work as expected on all platforms.  See [Socket.setSoTimeout(timeinSECONDS);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: I think @ashish means that he is able to establish connection, but is rather waiting for input. `checkTimeout` will wait for connection to get established

Comment: @Jatin You might be right, but such a checkTimeout can check what ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new thread for the server listener. Have the new thread set an internal toggle if it has received input from the server.

In your main thread, start a loop that waits until either the connection times out, or the server thread connects. If it connects, handle the server's input. If it doesn't, and it times out, kill the thread (and potentially close the connection).

Comment: So i have to have another thread apart from listener and timer ?? Anyway i can check both conditions in the same thread??

Comment: You can put the timer in your main thread - just make sure it doesn't hog the CPU. The server connection goes in its own thread, so it can be killed if needed.

Comment: Even if i have my timer in main thread, i need 2 more threads onr to toggle if i receive a msg and other to check which one satisfied(received msg or timer expired) ryt?

Answer (score 0):

In the given case, I think Polling is the best alternative as said by @Peter.
But one can also do it using 2 threads:

```
NetworkThread implements Runnable, Closeable{
BufferedReader r;
volatile boolean readyToClose = false;
@Override
public void run(){
//initialize r as t = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
String s = null;
while((s= r.readLine())!=null){
  readyToClose = true;
 //do whatever
}
}
public void close() throws IOException
{
   if(readyToClose()
     r.close();
}
}
```

Have another thread that will be blocked for that duration (`sleep`). And then will call `NetworkThread#close()`. This will close the stream and the other thread will come out of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CountdownLatch for this purpose. Start network thread, then call await on countdown latch:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

// start network thread
networkThread.start();

boolean wasFinished = latch.await(you_timeout);

// Interrupt network thread as it still waiting:
if(!wasFinished) {
    networkThread.interrupt();
}
```

In network thread after read succes call latch.countDown();

Comment: `readLine` does not come out due to interruption. It will still remain blocked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595926/how-to-interrupt-bufferedreaders-readline