# How to stop BufferedReader readline()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Im new to java and im trying to make client-server form. The client and server can chat each other. So my client have 2 thread for 2 mission: send and receive message. I want when my SendThread read from keyboard string "Bye", my client will stop 2 thread. But problem is the thread receive still perform the statement readline() of BufferedReader so it can't reach to the exit
Here is my code of mine:

```
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (!stop) {
                String temp = br.readLine();
                if (temp.length() == 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                else System.out.println(" Receiving from server: " + temp);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Update:** Sorry everyone because i dont explain more clearly. My client have 2 thread run independently. So ReceiveThread where this code is in can alway wait message from server. And SendThread also alway read data from keyboard. So when i type "Bye", SendThread read this string and stop client. Problem is ReceiveThread is performing `readLine()` so it can't stop itself.

Comment: `while (!stop)` strange condition since you're not changing `stop`.

Comment: `stop` will change when i close my SendThread. I dont post that code here

Comment: And do you close that thread if the server closed the socket? Since this is one of the conditions where you like to stop reading. And where do you handle the received message "Bye"? If "nowhere" when try to change your code so you can detect a closed stream or the message "Bye". The current answer might help you with that.

Comment: What's the sleep for? It's just literally a waste of time. Take it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) `null` reference will be returned when there is end of stream, so I would do this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String temp;
while ((temp=br.readLine())!=null) { //check null reference
    if (temp.length() == 0)
        Thread.sleep(100);
    else
        System.out.println(" Receiving from server: " + temp);
}
```

It this is not helpfull see [How to interrupt BufferedReader's readLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595926/how-to-interrupt-bufferedreaders-readline?rq=1)

Comment: According to the Javadoc, null is returned *at end of stream*, which means the peer has disconnected, which mean you should stop reading, exit the loop, and close the socket. Nothing to do with nothing to read'.

Comment: Corrected @EJP, +1 to your answer and explanation

Comment: Not really. You haven't actually shown how to answer the question. Hard to see what sleeping on a blank line does for you either.

Comment: Using `br.readLine==null` dont affect because my client need to listen message from server all time whatever server send anything or not.
But closing socket is really what i need.The link really help me :))

Comment: @G.U.N You've missed the point just like this poster did. It returns null when the peer has disconnected, and not before. It doesn't return null when the sender hasn't sent anything, and it doesn't provide any kind of a solution to this problem by itself. There's nothing here that justifies accepting this answer. The link doesn't say anything beyond what's been posted here in other answers. Clearly you haven't tried them.

Comment: @EJP Yes. It's my mistake. I didn't explain it clearly for everyone. 
But this link is really the answer i need. Next time I will be more careful.
Anyway, thank you for your help :))

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, Anyway, I am glad it works :), I havent tested it so... :D @EJP

Answer (score 6):

Shut the socket down for input, which will cause `readLine()` to return null, after which the read thread should close the socket.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do the same thing back to the client also ? when the server receives 'bye' send a 'byebye' to client and when client receives this exit.

At server

```
if (inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
    out.println("byebye");
    socket.close();
    break;
}
```

And at client

```
if (resp.equals("byebye")) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to stop readLine() by closing socket

```
    final Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    //  this thread will close socket in a second
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                s.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }.start();

    r.readLine();
```